# Looking for a project that allow me to create my own blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

I am looking for a project that allow me to create my own blockchain network. I just want the following features:

- Wallet creation
- Token Creation
- Execution of smartcontracts

I don't need something very complex, because I want to use it for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use Ethereum and run a private chain by yourself, that way it has all the functionality Ethereum has.

Here is brief tutorial: [private ethereum by example](https://medium.com/coinmonks/private-ethereum-by-example-b77063bb634f)

Comment: Very interesting approach, tks

Comment: Hi @MickMarosky if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.